# ELI5 the differences between sprites and traditional payment channels

Tags: payments, state-channels

There has been interest[[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05812)][[2](https://blog.enuma.io/update/2018/05/24/sprites-state-channels.html)] lately in sprites-style payment channels. Could someone provide a quick comparison?

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference with sprites over LN and similar payment channels is in the worst case scenario, where a party along a channel does not cooperate to sucessfully resolve the payment. This locks up the funds for the sender in time proportionally to the link length, since the whole dispute process needs to go back to each node one by one. In sprites, the time lock of the funds are constant since everything is managed by a smart contract (not possible to deploy sprites in bitcoin at the moment).